# Not able to properly nest GridView inside Cardview

Tags: java, android-layout, gridview, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I use a RecyclerView , which renders CardView . This CardView has 2 TextViews and one GridView , The GridView renders CardView (lets call it inside_card )as its child. Now i am unable to change height of this inside_card . Given below is what i want to achieve(Image A) and what i am getting (Image B).
[image: Reference Image]

Given Below are my Layouts.
**activity_main.xml** contains RecylerView

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".Activities.MainActivity">
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>  

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

**activity_card.xml** Contains Layout to be rendered inside RecyclerView

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView


        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#AAA"

        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/proffName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ProfessorName"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal">
            </TextView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subjectCode"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SemesterName"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">
        </TextView>

            <GridView
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/unitsGrid"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="6dp"
                android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
                android:numColumns="2"></GridView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

**inside_card.xml** contains layout to be rendered inside GridView

````
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

        android:id="@+id/inside_card"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
        app:cardElevation="6dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#eeeeee"
        >
        <TextView
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/unitName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:textColor="@color/cardview_dark_background"
            android:textSize="18dp" />
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView> ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Change in inside_card.xml

-> Increase the height of card view from 45dp to 120dp, tweak as per requirement

-> Set card elevation 0dp, as in the design A, there is no card elevation.

-> Even I will suggest, don't take card view for this, Just take simple LienarLayout and set a drawable shape with stroke for this. Because Setting border on card view is a little tedious task.

```
 <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/inside_card"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
    app:cardElevation="0dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#eeeeee"
    >
    <TextView
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/unitName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:textColor="@color/cardview_dark_background"
        android:textSize="18dp" />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView> `
```

In your GridView, set vertical spacing too

```
      <GridView
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/unitsGrid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="6dp"
            android:horizontalSpacing="15dp"
            android:verticalSpacing="15dp"
            android:numColumns="2"></GridView>
```

Comment: Changing layout_height deosn't work in CardView , although Vertical spacing worked.